# IE11 breaksdown after logging to website (asp.net 4)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

We have a website here at work and it works perfectly fine until IE11,
now after logging in, the website renders like the screenshot below...

Note: this only happens in the production server. IE11 renders the page just fine in my local machine.

[image: IE11 screenshot after logging in]

We've applied the hotfix for this issue found on another SO thread, which i cannot seem to find again (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600217) with no success.

I've added 
    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">` to force IE10 doctype rendering. Still no luck.

But what I've noticed on the network tab on ie11 dev tools is that everything that uses the `<%= ResolveClientUrl("")%>` results in a 404 error (see screenshot)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Update your server.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Comment: i did see that, but that's not as simple as it sounds. I'm also currently waiting for the boss to upload a browser file as mentioned on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440533/site-doesnt-display-correctly-in-ie11

Comment: browser file didn't work any suggestions about the resolveclienturl not finding the right path?

Comment: The problem is that ASP.Net is using cookieless sessions, because of the broken / missing browser config.

Comment: the answer listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244223/webform-dopostbackwithoptions-is-undefined-in-ie11-preview actually fixed this issue without updating to 4.5