# ASP.NET Website Compatability issue on IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, internet-explorer-11

I have a Website developed in ASP.NET which works fine in Chrome, Firefox browsers but not IE. It requires the Compatability to be set specifically in the browser. If we remove the compatability, the website is rendered useless.

Is there some solution to this other than putting in Meta Tags like :`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`

Comment: If you tell is what the exact compatibility issue is then we can help you get around it. Note that ASP.NET-MVC doesn't generate any 'bad' markup by itself so the ASP.NET comment is irrelevant (WebForms, on the other hand...)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have `mobile.browser` file in `/App_Browsers`.

The problem is that the mobile.browser file does not have an entry for IE 11 so it doesn't know how to treat it and by default it will send the response with an `application/xhtml+xml` header.

Two solutions:

1. Remove the mobile.browser file
2. Update the mobile.browser file to a recent version that has an entry for IE 11

Here is a write-up explaining my problem: [Incomplete HTML in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191420/incomplete-html-in-ie-11)