# IE11 always render page in Document mode EDGE on locally hosted website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, doctype, internet-explorer-11, ie-compatibility-mode

In IE11, my local hosted sites always renders with Document Mode= EDGE. Technically it should use doctype IE9, because of my page doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Below are steps i have preformed before posting

1. unchecked "**Display internet sites in Compatibility View**" from
   IE, also my compatibility view list is empty.
2. Check my machine.config,web.config(global),web.config(website).
   there is no Compatibility relevant configuration in them.
3. Also there is no metadata in my page the force browser to render it in
   EDGE mode.

My dev environment is Windows7 64bit, ASP.net 4.5 and  IIS 7.5

Thanks for reading the question.

Comment: read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx especially the section about Document Mode Changes in ie 11

Comment: yes but why use EDGE only on local environment, when published it works as expected and use IE9

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Website Compatability issue on IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491317/asp-net-website-compatability-issue-on-ie11)

Answer (score 0):

Your DOCTYPE declaration will trigger the highest mode available to the version of IE used to view the page.

To force the page to IE9 standards mode, add the following as the first line of your page's  section:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Please note that this may not be an ideal experience in the long run.  When you view the page using MS Edge, it will be rendered in Edge mode (since Edge does not support `x-ua-compatible`).  Also, the IE9 specific features you're hoping to rely on may have been removed in a more [recent version of IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#legacyAPIs).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance